# gulp.run() has been deprecated. Use task dependencies or gulp.watch task triggering instead

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-connect

I have an error with my gulpfile. Can anybody help me?

It works previously. But after I added gulp-watch plugin it crashes.

So what I need to use?

Here is my [Gulpfile.js](http://pastebin.com/qqXwhv8z).

Here is a log:

```
azat@pc:~/git/lasttest$ gulp
[18:01:25] Using gulpfile ~/git/lasttest/gulpfile.js
[18:01:25] Starting 'default'...
gulp.run() has been deprecated. Use task dependencies or gulp.watch task triggering instead.
[18:01:25] Starting 'server'...
[18:01:25] Finished 'server' after 18 ms
[18:01:25] Finished 'default' after 37 ms
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1156:14)
at listen (net.js:1182:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1267:5)
at ConnectApp.server (/home/azat/git/lasttest/node_modules/gulp-connect/index.js:57:19)
at new ConnectApp (/home/azat/git/lasttest/node_modules/gulp-connect/index.js:37:10)
at Object.module.exports.server (/home/azat/git/lasttest/node_modules/gulp-connect/index.js:170:12)
at Gulp.<anonymous> (/home/azat/git/lasttest/gulpfile.js:112:11)
at module.exports (/home/azat/git/lasttest/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/home/azat/git/lasttest/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use gulp's dependency system built in to the watch method.

```javascript
// default depends on 'server' so that the server is started before
// the watches are started
gulp.task('default', ['server'], function() {
  // run jade whenever files in src/jade change
  gulp.watch('src/jade/**', ['jade']);

  // run images whenever files in src/images change
  gulp.watch('src/images/**/*', ['images']);
});
```

I'm not sure you need gulp-batch here unless you are running something that changes many images at once.

Comment: No offence to you, but this (official) solution is conceptually wrong.